# Index Match function to look up a single cell across multiple ranges

Tags: excel, indexing, range, match

I have 3 data sets in 6 columns, here is a simple mock up to explain my question:

[image: Data Set]

My data is not all in columns A and B because I need to save space at the the top of my Excel worksheet. In a separate data set below this, I want to look up a cell value in columns A, C, and E and match the dollar amount in B, D, and F, respectively. The data in columns A, C, and E will each be unique values. I've tried various versions of index match but cannot get it to return a valid result. Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(B:F,A:E,"Joe")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That didn't work for me. It works through a probably inelegant solution that I figured out. Again I'm sure this is not concise but it's returning what I need:  =(IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$14,MATCH(H47,$B$2:$B$14,0),2),INDEX($E$4:$F$13,MATCH(H47,$F$4:$F$10,0),2)))